# Display latest blog list using WeBlog Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, weblog

I have installed WeBlog module in Sitecore. I have created sample blog, entry, category. Now i want to do 2 things.

1. Display latest blog in list format just like [this](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog.aspx)
2. On right side category is displaying, now I want to display corresponding blog on click of category.

Comment: Do you expect a ready solution?

Comment: Just want to know that this functionality is available on WeBlog or i have to create. If i have to create custom how can I get list of all blogs according to created date.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you have to create something custom using the tools WeBlog gives you - no different from Sitecore

There is a great video online showing you how to create a blog listing with WeBlog and I believe it covers displaying Categories and even Tag Clouds.

https://youtu.be/DGlyYP4PK28?t=15m17s

Definitely worth a watch as it'll give you want you require, however there doesn't seem to be any source code provided for the example he makes. However you'll know how to develop it from watching the video